# Do logistic functions have to be symmetrical?

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm attempting the find the equation of a graph i have plotted, which is S shaped similar to a logistic function. I want to use the logistic function equation to model it, but "top curve" of the S is longer than the first curve, meaning it isn't symmetrical.

Would it still be possible to use the equation (L/1+e^-k(x-x0) to model it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function